# Returning related fields of a model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an app with a rest API that should return values for instances of objects based on the url given. Right now I have the API working using ModelViewSets of my objects for the API.

For example I have three objects, user, transactions, and goals.

As it stands I can go to /mysite/api/users and return a list of all users
I can also go to /mysite/api/users/1 to return just the user with the id '1'.

I can do something similar with transactions and goals.

What I'm looking to do is go to url /mysite/api/users/1/transaction/1/goal

to find the goal associated with the transaction for that user.

I've been scouring tutorials and am not sure what the right question is to ask in order to find something useful to learn how to do this. What is the correct way to go about setting up my rest api like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create nested ressources.
If you are using `Viewsets`, then the `ExtendedRouter` class of the `drf-extensions` package will allow you to achieve this.

Drf-extensions documentation about this feature: https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes

There is also [this module](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers), who also offer the same features.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use url params or query params to solve your issue. I will explain the URL params solution here,

serializers.py

```
#Write a Goal Serializer
```

urls.py

```
#change the URL according to your environment
url(r'^users/(?P<uid>[0-9]+)/transaction/(?P<tid>[0-9]+)/goal/$', GoalViewSet.as_view({'get': 'user_transaction_goal',}), name='user-transaction-goal'),
```

views.py

```
class GoalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Goal.objects.all()

    def user_transaction_goal(self, request, uid, tid):
        #assuming user is FK in transaction and transaction is a FK in goal 
        #modify the filter rule according to your model design
        goals = Goal.objects.filter(transaction=tid, transaction__user=uid)
        serializer = GoalSerializer(goals, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

As @clement mentioned you can also use plugins to handle this situation.